# Javascript split by numbers using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will do following.
I have a string

`var input_string = "E100T10P200E3000T3S10";`

`var output=input_string.split(**Trying to find this**);`

this should give an array with all the letters in order with repetitions

`output = ["E","T","P","E","T","S"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below. `\d+` means one or more digits; `filter (x => x)` removes empty strings that can appear in the beginning or the end of the array if the input string begins or ends with digits.

```js
var input_string = "E100T10P200E3000T3S10";

var output = input_string.split (/\d+/).filter (x => x);

console.log (output);
```

Comment: Thank you Alexander for very early and elegant reply, this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex **replace** method. First replace all the digits with empty string and then split the resultant string.

```js
const input_string = 'E100T10P200E3000T3S10';
const ret = input_string.replace(/\d/g, '').split('');
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try just matching for capital letters here:

```js
var input_string = "E100T10P200E3000T3S10";
var output = input_string.match(/[A-Z]/g);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is spread the string to array and use [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) as filter callback

```js
var input_string = "E100T10P200E3000T3S10";

var output = [...input_string].filter(isNaN);

console.log(output);
```